# How do I delete all spooled files for another user on an AS400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Assuming I have the correct permissions, how can I delete all spooled files for another user on the AS400?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use the WRKSPLF command.  Prompt it and specify the user id.  Then put a 4 next to each spooled file.  If the user has many, many spooled files and you need to make this a repeatable process, then a program may be a better, longer term solution.

Answer (score 5):

To delete spool files wholesale you can use the DLTSPLF command:

```
                          Delete Spooled File (DLTSPLF)                         

 Type choices, press Enter.                                                     

 Spooled file . . . . . . . . . .                 Name, *SELECT                 
 Job name . . . . . . . . . . . .   *             Name, *                       
   User . . . . . . . . . . . . .                 Name                          
   Number . . . . . . . . . . . .                 000000-999999                 
 Spooled file number  . . . . . .   *ONLY         1-999999, *ONLY, *LAST, *ANY  
 Job system name  . . . . . . . .   *ONLY         Name, *ONLY, *CURRENT, *ANY   
 Spooled file created:                                                          
   Creation date  . . . . . . . .   *ONLY         Date, *ONLY, *LAST            
   Creation time  . . . . . . . .                 Time, *ONLY, *LAST            
 Select files for:                                                              
   User . . . . . . . . . . . . .   *CURRENT      Name, *CURRENT, *ALL          
   Print device . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          Name, *ALL, *OUTQ             
   Form type  . . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          Form type, *ALL, *STD         
   User data  . . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          User data, *ALL               
   ASP  . . . . . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          1-32, *ALL, *ASPDEV           
 ASP device . . . . . . . . . . .   *             Name, *, *SYSBAS, *CURASPGRP  
                                                                         Bottom 
 F3=Exit   F4=Prompt   F5=Refresh   F12=Cancel   F13=How to use this display    
 F24=More keys
```

Answer (score 1):

15 years ago I could have told you that instantly.  Now it's in the bit of my brain that I can't access anymore!

(update)
A quick google found this - [AS400 commands](http://martinri.freeshell.org/as400/as400-commands.html)  I don't have an AS400 at hand to test these commands but something like `HLDSPLF` (to hold the spool file) and `WRKSPLF` to display the administration menu for the spooler - and a menu option off that *should* have the delete command.

*Again, this is from very rusty memory.  YMMV*

(update again)
[WRKSPL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/cl/wrksplf.htm) command summary....

Answer (score 1):

`DLTSPLF FILE(*SELECT) SELECT(DESIRED_USER)`